# [PHP-RIAK]: How to display a part of some JSON data

Tags: php, json, decode, riak, querying

I am fetching `JSON` data from my riak database and I can display it using `print_r($data)`, but when I try to display the info associated with 'text' in the JSON data, I get this error message:

> PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
>   given in /var/www/html/index.php on line 33
>
> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 35

```
 <?php
    require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Riak.php');
    require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Bucket.php');
    require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Exception.php');
    require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Link.php');
    require_once('src/Basho/Riak/MapReduce.php');
    require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Object.php');
    require_once('src/Basho/Riak/StringIO.php');
    require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Utils.php');
    require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Link/Phase.php');
    require_once('src/Basho/Riak/MapReduce/Phase.php'); 
    $client = new Basho\Riak\Riak('172.31.42.72', 10018);
    $myBucket = $client->bucket('world');    // our bucket, world
    // fetches stored raw JSON data from riak database
    $fetched = $myBucket->get('542660947589230592');  
    //converts json string to an array
    $data = json_decode($fetched, true);  
    foreach ($data as $tweet) {
        echo $tweet->text, "<br>";
    }
?>
```

The raw JSON data is a tweet from twitter and BEFORE it has been decoded, I did a simple: `print_r($fetched)` check to see what is actually being fetched:

```
Basho\Riak\Object Object ( [meta:protected] => Array ( ) [indexes:protected] => Array ( ) [autoIndexes:protected] => Array ( ) [client] => Basho\Riak\Riak Object ( [host] => 172.31.42.72 [port] => 10018 [prefix] => riak [mapred_prefix] => mapred [indexPrefix] => buckets [clientid] => php_vpyij2 [r] => 2 [w] => 2 [dw] => 2 ) [bucket] => Basho\Riak\Bucket Object ( [client] => Basho\Riak\Riak Object ( [host] => 172.31.42.72 [port] => 10018 [prefix] => riak [mapred_prefix] => mapred [indexPrefix] => buckets [clientid] => php_vpyij2 [r] => 2 [w] => 2 [dw] => 2 ) [name] => world [r] => [w] => [dw] => ) [key] => 542660947589230592 [jsonize] => 1 [headers] => Array ( [http_code] => 200 [x-riak-vclock] => a85hYGBgzGDKBVIcJr1RG5yf1mVkMCUy5rEyMO75c5YvCwA= [vary] => Accept-Encoding [server] => MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.5 (jokes are better explained) [link] => ; rel="up" [last-modified] => Wed, 10 Dec 2014 12:43:45 GMT [etag] => "62oBuySAGsygcN9kgeB4ZG" [date] => Fri, 12 Dec 2014 09:58:52 GMT [content-type] => application/octet-stream [content-length] => 5026 ) [links] => Array ( ) [siblings] => [exists]
=> 1 [data] => Array ( [created_at] => Wed Dec 10 12:43:46 +0000 2014 [id] => 542660947589230592 [id_str] => 542660947589230592 [text] => RT @TrudoLemmens: Inspiring: Child rights activists Malala Yousafzai & Kailash Satyarthi receive joint Nobel award http://example.com [source] => Twitter Web Client [truncated] => [in_reply_to_status_id]
=> [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => [in_reply_to_user_id] => [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => [in_reply_to_screen_name] => [user] => Array ( [id] => 397692076 [id_str] => 397692076 [name] => Vassili Apostol. [screen_name] => v_apostol [location] => Toronto [url] => http://www.apostollaw.ca [description] => Lawyer writer father Ph.D in law candidate @ Osgoode | Health, employment, family, justice, rights, liberties, bioethics, books | I miss swimming in the Aegean [protected] => [verified] => [followers_count] => 200 [friends_count]
=> 304 [listed_count] => 10 [favourites_count] => 17 [statuses_count] => 4290 [created_at] => Tue Oct 25 01:27:15 +0000 2011 [utc_offset] => -18000 [time_zone] => Eastern Time (US & Canada) [geo_enabled] => [lang] => en [contributors_enabled] => [is_translator] => [profile_background_color] => 022330 [profile_background_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme15/bg.png [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme15/bg.png [profile_background_tile] => [profile_link_color] => 0084B4 [profile_sidebar_border_color] => A8C7F7 [profile_sidebar_fill_color]
=> C0DFEC [profile_text_color] => 333333 [profile_use_background_image] => 1 [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2963256714/99af4a287e550bc804d2689e8cc99ba3_normal.jpeg [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2963256714/99af4a287e550bc804d2689e8cc99ba3_normal.jpeg [default_profile] => [default_profile_image] => [following] => [follow_request_sent] => [notifications] => ) [geo] => [coordinates]
=> [place] => [contributors] => [retweeted_status] => Array ( [created_at] => Wed Dec 10 12:41:54 +0000 2014 [id] => 542660477612871680 [id_str] => 542660477612871680 [text] => Inspiring: Child rights activists Malala Yousafzai & Kailash Satyarthi receive joint Nobel award http://example.com [source] => Twitter for Websites [truncated] => [in_reply_to_status_id] => [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => [in_reply_to_user_id] => [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => [in_reply_to_screen_name] => [user] => Array ( [id] => 2440319112 [id_str] => 2440319112 [name] => Trudo Lemmens [screen_name] => TrudoLemmens [location] => Toronto [url] => http://www.law.utoronto.ca/faculty-staff/full-time-faculty/trudo-lemmens [description] => Professor of Law and Bioethics University of Toronto; disillusioned-yet-persistent cyclist in Toronto [protected] => [verified] => [followers_count] => 339 [friends_count] => 264 [listed_count] => 9 [favourites_count] => 6 [statuses_count] => 415 [created_at] => Sat Apr 12 17:32:55 +0000 2014 [utc_offset] => [time_zone] => [geo_enabled] => [lang] => en [contributors_enabled] => [is_translator] => [profile_background_color] => C0DEED [profile_background_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png [profile_background_tile] => [profile_link_color] => 0084B4 [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED [profile_sidebar_fill_color]
=> DDEEF6 [profile_text_color] => 333333 [profile_use_background_image] => 1 [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/455104260615569408/6OB88Oli_normal.png [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/455104260615569408/6OB88Oli_normal.png [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2440319112/1398742720 [default_profile] => 1 [default_profile_image] => [following] => [follow_request_sent] => [notifications] => ) [geo] => [coordinates]
=> [place] => [contributors] => [retweet_count] => 1 [favorite_count] => 0 [entities] => Array ( [hashtags] => Array ( ) [trends] => Array ( ) [urls] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => http://example.com [expanded_url] => http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-30411049 [display_url] => bbc.com/news/world-asiâ€¦ [indices] => Array ( [0] => 101 [1] => 123 ) ) ) [user_mentions] => Array ( ) [symbols] => Array ( ) ) [favorited] => [retweeted] => [possibly_sensitive] => [filter_level] => low [lang] => en ) [retweet_count] => 0 [favorite_count] => 0 [entities] => Array ( [hashtags] => Array ( ) [trends] => Array ( ) [urls] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => http://example.com [expanded_url] => http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-30411049 [display_url] => bbc.com/news/world-asiâ€¦ [indices] => Array ( [0] => 119 [1] => 141 ) ) ) [user_mentions] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [screen_name] => TrudoLemmens [name] => Trudo Lemmens [id] => 2440319112 [id_str] => 2440319112 [indices] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 16 ) ) ) [symbols] => Array ( ) ) [favorited] => [retweeted] => [possibly_sensitive] => [filter_level] => medium [lang] => en [timestamp_ms] => 1418215426715 ) )
```

Comment: it goes wrong because what you got isn't a json, is an object. You can iterate inside it

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should simply ignore decoding? But that hasn't worked either, maybe I missunderstood you. How would I make this object a json then?

Comment: jsonEncode command i think

Comment: Hm, that gives me:

_Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/index.php on line 43_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your problem.

```
//converts json string to an array
  $data = json_decode($fetched, true);
```

Because `$myBucket->get()` return the `Basho\Riak\Object`.
Test with this code

```
// fetches stored raw JSON data from riak database
$fetched = $myBucket->get('542660947589230592');  

//get data array
$data = $fetched->getData();

foreach ($data as $tweet) {
    echo $tweet['text'];
}
```

Comment: Okay, after making the changes I now get this printed on my webpage:

`W5R`

Shouldn't I get something like:  _"RT @TrudoLemmens: Inspiring: Child rights activists Malala Yousafzai & Kailash Satyarthi receive joint Nobel award http://t.co/77SzhtIMSW "_ ?

Comment: Ah, I changed the last line and now the tweet is being printed! `echo $tweet['text']."\n";` I added the "\n". I guess it needed instructions to how it should be formatted in the print. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**1. Test/debug your code and data**

Why do you think, that your `$fetched` variable contents a JSON string? Output of `print_r()` shows, that it is an object (`var_dump()` could show this exactly).

**2. Check the documentation or library code**

From the [github code](https://github.com/basho/riak-php-client/blob/develop/src/Basho/Riak/Bucket.php):

```
/**
* Retrieve a JSON-encoded object from Riak.
*
* @param string $key - Name of the key.
* @param int $r - R-Value of the request (defaults to bucket's R)
* @return Object
*/
public function get($key, $r = null)
{
    $obj = new Object($this->client, $this, $key);
    $obj->jsonize = true;
    $r = $this->getR($r);
    return $obj->reload($r);
}
```

Bucket's `get()` method returns with a `\Basho\Riak\Object`.

The library hides the JSON based protocol, and provides parsed data. Instead of `json_decode()`, you should use `->getData()`.